# running MongoDB using mongod.exe

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, cmd

I have the mongoDB works well in my computer . 
but every time I want to run it I should go to the CMD and type :

```
c:\mongoDB\bin\mongod --dbpath c:\mongoDB\data\db
```

and if I close the CMD window the connection will ends up . 
So I'm wondering if I want to upload my App to online website , how should the mongoDB works !? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [run mongodb as a Windows service](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/01/running-mongodb-as-windows-service.html)

e.g. set up as a windows service

```
mongod --install --serviceName "MongoDB" --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db 
       --logpath C:\mongodb\logs\mongolog.txt --logappend
```

Then you can start the service from CMD using:

```
net start mongodb
```

Or, you can start it via Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services. You can then just set it to start automatically on Windows start.

Comment: right I'm gonna do that but where to type : mongod --install ... etc . in the CMD or maybe mongo.exe . and if I have uploaded my App to example.com the mongoDB should works well !?! without any configurations !?

Comment: @Rawhi - you run that in the cmd from the mongodb bin directory.

Comment: I've tried to run this statement in CMD from start :D and gives me this error : mongo is not recognized .. etc

Comment: You need to run "mongod" from the bin directory of mongodb. Check out the link